# How to add Slicer to Pivot Table using Python win32com?

Tags: python, excel, automation, win32com

I am trying to add Slicer to Pivot Table using Python win32com. I don't understand how to add Slicer.

I've tried various methods but it's not helping.

Answer (score 0):

I used this example: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/ze2ndf/creating_slicers_with_xlwings/

The excel version would look like this:
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches.Add2(ActiveSheet.PivotTables("DataSource"), _
"SlicerField").Slicers.Add ActiveSheet, , "SlicerName", "SlicerName" _
, 100, 700, 1837, 701

And this is the python win23com version :

`workbook.SlicerCaches.Add2(worksheet.PivotTables("DataSource"),"SlicerField").SlicersAdd(worksheet, Name="SlicerName", Top=100, Left=700, Width=1837, Height=701)`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34604653)